# size of popup window

Tags: javascript, html

How to set the width and height of a pop up window in html..

I used the following piece of code..

```
  window.open('customerlist.jsp?salespersonid=<%=salespersonid%>&flag=<%=tempite%>','popupwindow','width=50 ,height=50')
```

It is working fine in IE but other browser displaying popup window in full screen instead of specified dimensions. What are the options for using in other browsers??

IE result:
[image: IE Screenshot]

Chrome result:
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) states that `height` and `width` minimum values are `100`, where you have `50`.

Comment: I checked given window open method code snippet in Chrome and Firefox. It display correctly with give height and width. See http://jsfiddle.net/VXF6L/  But I think it is better if you have mentioned the units of the width and height there, like 50px instead of just 50.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use jquery for popups. Standard plugins render well in all browsers. You can start right away with jquery simple modal plugin. If you still want to use window.open , this link shall be very useful http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html .

With simple modal, you will have to include your popup html code in the same page over which you want to display it. Keep it inside a div. and then add this pi9ece of code

```
    $(function(){
      $(".your_button").click(){
        $(".your_div").modal(); 
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, you have to set "status=0" to get it to behave properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be the solution. I didnt try it.

```
w2=window.open("http://www.java2s.com","mywin","width=400,height=300,screenX=50,left=50,screenY=50,top=50,status=yes,menubar=yes");
```

Then you can connect to window that you opened.

```
w2.resizeTo( 400,300 );
```